# Reset particular layer in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, layers

I have two layers in my GEE and I want to reset one of them base on my selector. I have the code as following:

```
Map.layers().reset(['UHI']); 
Map.addLayer(UHIAdded, {opacity: 0.5}, 'layer1');  
Map.addLayer(uhiday, {min: -2.0, max: 3.0, palette: palette, opacity: 0.5}, 'UHI');
```

And there's the error:

> Cannot add an object of type string as a layer.

If I get rid of the `[]`, it will give me the error:

> The argument provided to `ui.List.reset()` must be an array.

How do I specify the layer that I want to reset?

Answer (score 3):

Without a working example it will be dificult to help you, below is an example that could help you with the logic of using `.reset()`.

I'm assuming you are trying to use it for building widgets of some sort? It needs to be an ee.Map.Layer I think, before you can reset it:

```
var one = ui.Map.Layer(ee.Image(1))
var two = ui.Map.Layer(ee.Image(2))

Map.layers().reset([two]);
```

Comment: Just to expand this a bit. Here is an example that adds two layers to the `Map` and then replaces one of them with a new layer using `reset`. [Code Editor script](https://code.earthengine.google.com/0e2ba24a742e172e761acd328f575281)

Comment: ...and at least in these examples, there is no need to cast the `ee.Image` as a `ui.Map.Layer`